# Custom Project Templates with Wizard Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I want to create a custom project template with wizard i.e. when I create a new project, I will select my custom project template and it will immediatly show me the wizard or a screen which takes some form of input and process that input and creates corresponding project. Is it possible to do that same? I have googled a lot but to no avail becoz I found most of the samples which just creates the template but not the wizard.

I want to develop a project template same as ASP.NET MVC, when we create a new ASP.NET MVC project it asks for the test cases an the stuff (A screen appears which asks for some input and based on that input it creates a MVC web application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an assembly containing an implementation of Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.IWizard and installit in the GAC, then add a corresponding tag in the template description file.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx) about VS Templates. In particular, [how to create a wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx) for template project customization.

And here's an old tutorial about [how to create a simple VS Template](http://www.carlosag.net/Articles/createVSTemplate.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Castle MonoRail VS integration project as a sample https://svn.castleproject.org/svn/castle/trunk/Tools/VSNetWizard or via FishEye http://fisheye2.atlassian.com/browse/castleproject/trunk/Tools/VSNetWizards